# GetWindowLongPtr fails returning Retrieves the user data

Tags: c++, winapi

I created win32 wrapper before but I lost the files...  So I'm gonna creating them again.  The problem is with my router(static window processor).
Here is my code

```
CFramework *wnd = 0; 

// retrieve associated Window instance 
wnd = reinterpret_cast<CFramework *>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA)); 

// call the windows message handler 
wnd->WndProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

return true;
```

When I call `GetWindowLongPtr` it won't retrieves the user data.
**UPDATE:**
I also tired this code that uses SetWindowLongPtr

```
if ( msg == WM_CREATE ) 
   { 
       SetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams ); 
   } 

   Window *targetApp = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA ); 

   if ( targetApp ) 
   { 
       return targetApp->WndProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam ); 
   } 

   return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
```

I used my second code.^^^^
I put break point at SetWindow...
It seems it never Get called!

Comment: Well, that's probably because you forgot to put it in first.  Search SetWindowLongPtr().

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtr` is known to work. Where do you call `SetWindowLongPtr`? Are you checking error codes. Do all your API calls succeed? If not, what error codes are returned?

Comment: @David It compiles with no errors or warnings

Comment: @Ramilol Not the compiler errors! The errors that Windows returns when the win32 functions you call fail. `GetLastError` tells you the error code and but you need to understand how each function reports errors, they are differences across win32.

Comment: [Raymond Chen says of GWLP_USERDATA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/03/384285.aspx) "this value, like the other window extra bytes and the messages in the WM_USER range, belongs to the window class and not to the code that creates the window." Perhaps it's being overwritten by the window's own WndProc? I'm fairly sure MFC uses its own HWND to CWnd* mapping in thread local storage to do this, not GetWindowLongPtr.

Comment: @Rup If OP was using MFC then this code would not be needed, it would just replicate CWnd. But it could well be a wrapper for one of the standard window classes which may stomp on this.

Comment: @David Sure - I meant that as "here's how MFC solved the problem you're trying to solve"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your window may receive some messages before `WM_CREATE`.  I did something like this a while ago, and there were sizing and positioning messages, along with `WM_NCCREATE`, that arrived before the `WM_CREATE`.  So you shouldn't expect to see the value there on those messages.

Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?  If 64-bit, then the cast to `LONG` may be whacking your pointer.

And, as Rup said in the comments, you have to be really certain that nobody else is using `WM_USERDATA`.

Comment: @ram  you've got your answer now?